# Paypal Express Checkout ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to implement Paypal express checkout using activemerchant 1.53 in ruby on rails 4.2.3. After following the railscasts video given here http://railscasts.com/episodes/146-paypal-express-checkout, I've managed to get the basic order flow working without any visible errors. However I've two remaining issues-

- The response.success? in purchase method in order.rb always returns a false. This returns a false even when I get a value for express_payer_id and express_token in my db for that particular order.
- I donot see a credit in business account or a debit in personal buyer account. Both accounts are created in paypal sandbox environment. Also, I donot see log of any transaction.
- How do I extract shipping address and email from token, I was able to extract first name and last name as given in railscasts.

I understand m question is bit vague, but please let me know what information do I need to provide to help debug the problem as I cannot see any error in the log. A user gets routed from my site in development environment to Paypal, enters the details of their Paypal sandbox account, completes the transaction, gets redirected to my site, completes the order. Everything works without an error until he gets greeted with a failure message as response.success? returns a false.

Any pointers that would help me debug the problem will be appreciated. Is there any Paypal log I can look at to see what is happening at their end ? Or is there any log I can generate from my end in rails and provide you to help debug? Have the Paypal API or the activemerchant methods changed now as the railscasts is quite old.?

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The rails debugging options helped me to debug my problem. I added the following lines in my controller and model to analyse the responses provided by Paypal API.
It turns out that i was passing the ip address and total amount as nil in the purchase function resulting in a failure response.

```
logger.debug "first response: #{response.inspect}"
logger.debug "total price: #{total_price.inspect}"
logger.debug "Express_purchase_opt: #{express_purchase_options.inspect}"
```

Hope this helps other people who come across similar problem!.